# Can't access Java from shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to execute a jar file from a bash script, but for whatever reason, java subcommands are not working within the shell script. Attached is an example of a simple script, and the error it returns. The same error is outputted when I use any subcommand for java.

What do I need to fix?

```
#!/bin/sh
java -version
```

[image: Error Picture]

Comment: The error message indicates that `java` was found and was doing something but exited because of some issue. What happens when you type `java -version` on the command line? Have you tried "version" with two dashes before it?

Comment: Your file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: try `echo $(java -version)` after the first line.

Comment: @t0mm13b — what's the advantage of that (`echo $(java -version)`) over simply running `java -version`?

Comment: @KamilCuk If that's correct; good diagnostics. How did you get there?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler to capture the output into a variable if required

Comment: @MartinYork the same error displays when adding two dashes. Upon using the command line, the command returns the expected output. https://imgur.com/95Pc0Mn

Comment: @MartinYork `How did you get there?` The line `: not found test.sh:` starts with a `:`. It looks like: `shell: test.sh: \r: not found`, but the `: not found` part was moved to the beginning of the line. And also `-version` does not work, which would not if it would be `-version$'\r'`.

Comment: @KamilCuk That's a worthy answer that people should be able to find via searching. Post an answer and I'll give you an up vote.